# Firebase token expired

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swift4

1. I have been struggling to solve the follwoing issue:
   The user token gets expired and I dont know how to handle this. Is
   there any way to get notified when the token is expired? How can I
   renew the token. I have been renewing the token on every launch of
   the app. Is this a right way or do we have any other way to do
   this?

   ```
   FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in   
     if user != nil {
       // User is signed in. Show home screen   
     } else {
       // No User is signed in. Show user the login screen   } 
   }
   ```

   Even this block is not capturing that state.

Comment: How about this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it doesn’t happen that way..even i can login to multiple apps with the same credentials..it happens sometime..like you close the app and open it next day..you get inside the app but data wont come as your token is expired..how can we detect the expiration of token when app is closed..we need to capture it when app opens..i just dont know how..

Comment: You might need to handle errors like: `FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidUserToken` properly and have the user to resign in

Comment: Thank you @zero3nna, I have firebase in my app just for login, after that i don't use firebase anywhere, then how will i know that the token is expired..??

Comment: check these error codes https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Enums/FIRAuthErrorCode

Answer (score 0):

You can get Firebase errors and return them to the user or you can use them as a notification. This can be achieved by doing the following:

First, check for the error. Then, get the error code. You can check the error code for `.userTokenExpired`.

```
if let error = error {
    if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code) {
        if errorCode == .userTokenExpired {
            print("The user's token has expired.")
        }
    }
}
```